# detecting dialect in Racket

Tags: racket

I would like to write code that is correct for both untyped Racket and typed/racket...

For now, I've come up with the following not-so-satisfying principle: I insert a dummy syntax definition for ':' at the beginning of the file, so that the annotations are skipped when using untyped racket. And I comment this definition when using typed/racket.

E.g:

```
#lang racket
; comment the following line for typed/racket
(define-syntax : (syntax-rules () ((_ id type) (void))))
(: fact (-> Integer Integer))

; the rest of the file is common to both racket and typed/racket
(define (fact n) (if (zero? n) 1 (* n (fact (sub1 n)))))
```

and

```
#lang typed/racket
; comment the following line for typed/racket
;(define-syntax : (syntax-rules () ((_ id type) (void))))
(: fact (-> Integer Integer))

; the rest of the file is common to both racket and typed/racket
(define (fact n) (if (zero? n) 1 (* n (fact (sub1 n)))))
```

This way I just need to remove/insert a ';' to switch between racket and typed/racket...

But is there a way to have a code that doesn't need any change to run in racket and typed/racket? I didn't find how to programmatically detect if I'm in racket or typed/racket... Then I guess I would also have to find a way to conditionally define ':' at the top-level... All this doesn't seem the way to go, so, is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you want code to work with both `#lang racket` and `#lang typed/racket`, just write your code in `#lang typed/racket`. When you require a module written in `#lang typed/racket` from a module written in `#lang racket`, contracts will automatically be inserted between the two modules to enforce the types. You don’t have to do anything special to require a typed module from an untyped one, so from the user’s perspective, they don’t have to care.

The one area where you might need to worry about being in a typed or untyped context is when writing macros. Often, you can expand to the same code in both situations, but sometimes, you have to do things differently depending on whether or not the target code is typed. For that, you can use [`define-typed/untyped-identifier`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/Utilities.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed%2Funtyped-utils..rkt%29._define-typed%2Funtyped-identifier%29%29), which allows specifying two different forms to be used in different contexts.

If you *really* need to detect whether or not the current expansion context is typed, you can use the large hammer [`syntax-local-typed-context?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/Utilities.html#%28def._%28%28lib._typed%2Funtyped-utils..rkt%29._syntax-local-typed-context~3f%29%29). However, the documentation itself recommends avoiding its use:

> This is the nuclear option, provided because it is sometimes, but rarely, useful. Avoid.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this is the way to go for "software engineering" purposes: a typed/racket module that can be invoked either by untyped or typed code... But this means this module of code is only compiled in a typed context: what if I would like to be able to compare untyped Racket and typed Racket (benchmarks for example) ?

Comment: Maybe it's a silly question... after all, typed and untyped are two different dialects (type annotations are not understood by untyped racket, and untyped racket code is not good enough for typed/racket), but my question arose from the fact typed code gives a code base that can be compiled/run in both standard racket (without the type annotations) and typed racket (with the type annotations).

Comment: @Euphoric Perhaps `#lang typed/racket/no-check` would do the trick for your needs, based on what you’ve said?

Comment: It does! I mean if `#lang racket` and `#lang typed/racket/no-check` generate the same code... At least, this is much better than the ugly trick I was using: typed annotations are properly processed (and ignored?)...